# VBA macro for excel. Mark row if cells in column A are the same but different in column C

Tags: vba

I do not have any code yet as I dont know VBA that much or at all.
I got excell sheet with 4 columns. Column A is main group and C is subgroups within groups from column A.

i need to mark somehow rows where within same JobID, WFID is the same and where WFID is different within same JobID.

```
JobID   TaskID   WFID
39822   913914  Complete
39822   913915  no complete
37941   905439  Complete
37941   905440  Complete
```

Would you be able to help pleasE?

Comment: You'll know from all your Python questions that SO doesn't work this way. If you don't know any VBA, then this post and tag are a little pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not really need macros to identify your rows.

Simply put this formula in a new column

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$8,A1,$C$1:$C$8,"<>"&C1)
```

Wherever there are different values in col C for same value of col A it will throw a 1 else 0

If you want to highlight, I recommend using conditional formatting based on the value of your new column with (0/1) values.

Hope this answers your query.